# Charles works on browser, but not on application - Android

Tags: android, ssl, networking, charles-proxy

I have installed and have been using charles proxy(4.5.6).

I am using Android 9.

Charles works on the Chrome pages (Instagram specifically):

[image: Charles and Instagram on chrome]

but it does not work on the Instagram application:

[image: Charles and Insta app]

and I always get that error when I am using the app.

Should I "Save Charles root certificate" and then install it on my phone? Also, why does Charles work on the Chrome but not on the Instagram app?

Answer (score 11):

Instagram's app uses a technique known as [SSL Certificate Pinning](https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e).  Basically, this means they bundle information about the expected SSL certificate for the server into the app, and deny any connection that doesn't present that certificate.  Because the certificate presented by Charles is not Instagram's certificate, the connection is denied by the Instagram app.  In Chrome, it must rely on the browser's assessment of certificate trust, which will defer to certificates installed on the device - I assume you've already set up your device to trust the Charles Proxy SSL certificate, so because Chrome trusts it (because you told it to), the website works.  There used to be [a way to do key pinning in the browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning), but it no longer works due to [some issues that were discovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning#Criticism_and_decline).

You can disable this certificate pinning in your Facebook account settings: https://www.facebook.com/whitehat/researcher-settings/

As for the details of their implementation, there are [numerous articles online](https://www.google.com/search?q=instagram%20certificate%20pinning) about how to disable the pinning in Instagram's app.  I can't vouch for any of them in particular, as I haven't tried them, and I'm not sure how they would interact with the terms of service, but you could take a look at those for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I have been working with Charles to monitor and debug network requests for my app and I would like to mention few points that would help you:

1. If you look at the documentation of [Charles SSL Certificate](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) for Android,

> As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in order to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL Proxying. **This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps that you control.**

This restriction has been added by the Android framework itself to avoid exploits and hacks for more security. So, you cannot use Charles to montior or debug network requests of third party apps (in your case -Instagram) if you're having Android 7 (Nougat) or higher.

If you really want to do it, you can try connecting an Android phone with Android 6 (Marshmallow) or lower to see if it works for you.

2. If you want to debug your own app, your phone and the system running Charles should be on the same network and you need to setup proxy configuration in your phone's Wi-Fi settings.

First go to *Charles -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Root Certificate on Mobile Device or Remote Browser*

You'll see an info window like this:

[image: Charles Connection to Android]

Note the IP address mentioned in this window and go to your phone's S*ettings -> Wi-Fi -> Select your Wi-Fi network -> Edit*

You'll find option called **Proxy**, it will be *None* by default, update it to **Manual**. You'll get two input fields for entering **Hostname and Port**, fill those details by looking at the IP mentioned in the Charles and Save it.

[image: Android Wi-Fi Settings]

3. Another important point is, you'll need to install Charles Root Certificate on your phone. You can do it by visiting https://chls.pro/ssl from your phone's browser. It'll automatically download the certificate and will prompt you to install it. Make sure you're connected to Charles by following the 2nd step, otherwise it won't download the certificate automatically.

Once it's done, you're good to go!

Comment: I have done all of that before. That is how I set up Charles. And can you see what Instagram app looks like in Charles?

Answer (score 1):

There may be two reason for this

1) The instagram app is using network security configuration file which disabled the proxy servers
for more information read this website https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

2) For checking payload of your own application you need to set proxy server
 as https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121